# How do I find the value at a certain position in an Array in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to iterate through an Array and find the sum of the odd, and the even positioned values.

Here is what I have, but I'm getting the error:
`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'`

```cs
static void SumOfOddsAndEvens(Array arr)
        {
            int i = 0;
            bool isEven = true;
            int evenSum = 0;
            int oddSum = 0;

            while (i < arr.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);

                if (isEven) evenSum += arr[i]; // Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'
                if (!isEven) oddSum += arr[i];
                isEven = !isEven;
                i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sum of even slots: " + evenSum);

            Console.WriteLine("Sum of odd slots: " + oddSum);
        }
```

Function is being called here:

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SumOfOddsAndEvens(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 });
        }
```

Comment: why do you use `Array`, when you actually pass `int[]`?

Comment: Am I not passing an array that way?

Comment: sure, within your main you´re passing a `new int[]`, which is then converted to `Array`-class, which does not have an indexer defined.

Comment: What if someone calls this method passing a `string[]`? The code will compile and fail at runtime. Don't use `Array`, not even for `object[]` parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although all arrays in C# derive from the [base-class `Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0), the latter does not define an indexer. Thus you can´t use `arr[i]` when `arr` is just an `Array`.

However I wonder why you even use that base-class, instead of the actual one, which is `int[]` in your case:

```
static void SumOfOddsAndEvens(int[] arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool isEven = true;
    int evenSum = 0;
    int oddSum = 0;

    while (i < arr.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);

        if (isEven) evenSum += arr[i];
        if (!isEven) oddSum += arr[i];
        isEven = !isEven;
        i++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sum of even slots: " + evenSum);

    Console.WriteLine("Sum of odd slots: " + oddSum);
}
```

Using the base-class would also allow the following, which is pure non-sense:

```
SumOfOddAndEvens(new[] { "Hello",  "World" };
```

or even this:

```
SumOfOddAndEvens(new object[] { 1, "World" };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an indexer on an Array. The Array class is a base class for all array types, and arrays are implicitly inherit from Array. But, Array itself doesn't have an indexer. Here is a demonstration of your error:

```
int[] numbers = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

numbers[2] = 11; // Okay

Array arr = numbers as Array;

arr[2] = 11; // ERROR!
```

You are creating your parameter right (`new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 }`) but in the SumOfOddsAndEvens function you are actually using Array type. (`static void SumOfOddsAndEvens(Array arr)`).
Just change this last one to *int[]* and you will be able to use an indexer with it.